# Adding bar gaps in a custom series in echarts

Tags: typescript, echarts

I'm having a bit of a tough time trying to get my bars, in a custom series eChart, to no overlap, see screen shot below.

The data that I'm adding here all have a few seconds to a minute between them, for example, on the first row, there are actually 2x orange bars overlapping, due to the time lapse of:

start - 12:05
end - 12:15

and

start - 12:15
end - 12:45

It has to do with the clipping, unfortunately, various attempts at getting this to work, has not been fruitful.

Here's an example of the item rendering on the x-axis:

```js
const index = api.value(0);
const start = api.coord([api.value(7), index]);
const end = api.coord([api.value(6), index]);

const coordsys = params.coordSys;
this.cartesianXBounds[0] = coordsys.x;
this.cartesianXBounds[1] = coordsys.x + coordsys.width;
this.cartesianYBounds[0] = coordsys.y;
this.cartesianYBounds[1] = coordsys.y + coordsys.height;

const barlength = end[0] = start[0];

const barheight = api.size([0, 1])[1] * 0.6;

const x = start[0];
const y = start[1] - barheight;

const rectNormal = this.clipRectByRect(params, {
  x,
  y,
  width: barlength,
  height: barheight
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add gap it will affect bars and move from real position to position + gap.  Screenshot not contains axes if it right and on real chart you have the same then just to add transparent micro-bar between.

Also you can take a look on [official example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=custom-profile): on #35 row where to BaseTime (bar length) incrementing random value to implement gap. And if you try to remove random gap the bars still won't overlap, use this as reference to check first your data and then your draw function.

P.S. If `start - 12:05 end - 12:15` and `start - 12:15 end - 12:45` on the same timeline then it's wrong. Second bar should start from 12:16 or first should end at 12:14 otherwise you will get overlap 1 sec.

[image]

Comment: thank you for this, it definitely helped me in the right direction.